Need to check this proof that the class of models of ZC that fail replacement is not axiomatisable.
Here ZC is ZFC minus Axiom of Replacement.
My proof is as follows:
Suppose $M$ was axiomatized by a theory $H$.
For non-zero limit ordinal $\alpha$, let $T_\alpha$ be the set of the replacement axioms for which the corresponding function-classes have domain a subset of $V_\alpha$. Then since every set is contained in some $V_\alpha$, we have that $\bar{H}=H\cup\bigcup_{0<\alpha \text{ limit ordinal}} T_\alpha$ has no model because the axiom of replacement would both hold and fail for any model of $\bar{H}$.
Let $H' \subset \bar{H}$ be a finite subset, and $\alpha$ a limit ordinal with cofinality larger than any ordinal mentioned in $H'$. Then we have $V_\alpha$ is a model of $H'$. Also $\alpha \notin V_\alpha$ so replacement fails in $V_\alpha$.
Hence by Compactness, $\bar{H}$ has a model. Contradiction, so $M$ not axiomatisable.
I am specifically in doubt about the part involving the set-wise definition of $T_\alpha$ and the "class-wise" definition of the axiom of replacement, meaning that $\bigcup T_\alpha$ might not be the whole replacement scheme. Does this matter? I'm also not sure about the cofinality bit.
Is this a reasonable proof? How do I make it more watertight? I know there are other proofs for this but I want to try it without any results beyond compactness or incompleteness theorem.
Thank you !

Your definition of $T_\alpha$ does not make sense since ordinals in a model are not necessarily the same objects in ordinals (in the metatheory).

There is a slight chance we are thinking of different things so I edited the definition to make it more clear. Can you see of anyway to fix the problem? For example if the $T$ axioms were defined in terms of the maximum rank increase that an application of the replacement axiom can have, rather than by the domain of the function-class?

I don't think you fixed the issue. Your proof lies in a misconception about ordinals in a model of set theory and true ordinals, and I don't see a way to fix your proof with slight modification.

@HanulJeon Do you think there is a way to do it with Compactness as above? Do ordinals in models not have any relation to true ordinals at all?

Regarding your latter question, sometimes they have, but not in general. If a model is transitive, then its ordinal agrees with the true ordinals, but not every model of set theory is transitive.

@HanulJeon How about now? I don't see why it would be relevant that the ordinals do not agree in other models. We only need to exhibit a model for each finite subset of the theory H and that model can be $V_\alpha$ for sufficiently large $\alpha$.

I think your argument is irreparable, and here is a list of errors.

For non-zero limit ordinal $\alpha$, let $T_\alpha$ be the set of the replacement axioms for which the corresponding function-classes have domain a subset of $V_\alpha$.

Here is the first part of your error: You assumed as if the theory $T$ knowns $\alpha$ is an ordinal. But $\alpha$ has not been a part of the language of set theory, which is the language of $T$. There is no way for $T$ to refer to $\alpha$ unless $\alpha$ is definable.

Then since every set is contained in some $V_\alpha$, we have that $\bar{H}=H\cup\bigcup_{0<\alpha \text{ limit ordinal}} T_\alpha$ has no model because the axiom of replacement would both hold and fail for any model of $\bar{H}$.

You started with your argument by "every set is contained in some $V_\alpha$." First, its proof requires Replacement (since defining $V_\alpha$ uses transfinite recursion, which is a consequence of Replacement.) Thus $H$ may not know how to refer to $V_\alpha$.
Second, and more seriously, you conflate the object theory and the metatheory again by referring to sets in the metatheory to conclude $\bar{H}$ has no model. The word 'sets' in the prior part denotes the true sets (or sets over the metatheory), but the 'sets' in the latter part denotes members of $\bar{H}$. However, there is no reason to assume these two are the same concept unless the model is transitive: If $(M,E)$ is a model of set theory, then $E$ can be different from $\in$. Thus, for example, it is possible that an non-empty set $a\in M$ satisfies $M\vDash \forall \lnot x (x \mathrel{E} a)$, meaning that $M$ thinks $a$ is the empty set.

But is it not true that for any one axiom of the replacement axiom schema there is some $V_\alpha$ which is a model of that axiom?

@Adam It is true by the reflection principle.

Is there a way to do it without the reflection principle? I would have thought that one could just apply the axiom a bunch of times and consider the maximum rank obtained.

@Adam I don't understand the meaning of "applying the axiom a bunch of times." There is no way to apply the axiom to get a new ordinal. Do you mean applying the class function instantiating the replacement schema?

Even if my understanding is correct, you should know that even the same formula may give a different class function on $V$ and $V_\alpha$ unless $V_\alpha$ is correct on the class function defining formula (that is, $\phi\leftrightarrow \phi^{V_\alpha}$.) Thus a form of reflection principle is unavoidable. Meanwhile, it would help if you looked at the proof of reflection principle in which applying class ordinal functions to get a new ordinal appears.
